# Android Retrofit get array from web service

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

this below `jsonArray` is out result of web service:

```
{
    "property":
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "qqqqqqq",
        "alias": "wwwwwwwww"
    },
    "foodList":
    [
        {
            "meal": "1111",
            "food": "1111111111"
        },
        {
            "meal": "22222",
            "food": "2222222222"
        },
        {
            "meal": "3333333",
            "food": "3333333333"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i'm try to get and parse it, but i get this error:

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was
BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 131 path $.foodList
```

class model like with result:

```
public class FoodLists {
    private String userId;
    private Property property;
    private FoodList foodList;

    public class Property {
        private int id;
        private String title;
        private String alias;

        /* Setter and Getters*/
    }
    public class FoodList {
        private String meal;
        private String food;

        /* Setter and Getters*/
    }

    /* Setter and Getters*/
}
```

and my retrofit method to get that:

```
private void getUserFoodsLists() {
    FoodLists getFoods = new FoodLists();
    getFoods.setUserId("301323");
    Call<FoodLists> call = behandamService.getFoodListsCall(getFoods);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<FoodLists>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<FoodLists> call, Response<FoodLists> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<FoodLists> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Err: ", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

how can i get this array with retrofit, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was
>   BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 131 path $.foodList

means that the response is returning a `JsonArray` but you told `Gson` to parse it as `JsonObject`. In your model class, change

```
 FoodList foodList;
```

with

```
 List<FoodList> foodList;
```

Answer (score 0):

The model of `FoodLists` you currently have does not match the JSON response you receive from your server, thus you get the error.

You have two options here - the obvious one is to change your POJO to match the response (a valid POJO was provided in one of the other answers). Drawback here is that the POJO might look ugly and have some information you don't really need.

There's another option which is better in case you want to keep your POJOs clean, perhaps if you're using them somewhere else, e.g. as database models or something else.
In this case you can use a custom [JsonDeserializer](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) and do the conversion from your response to the desired POJO manually. If you're interested in this approach, [HERE](http://veskoiliev.com/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-response-with-retrofit/) is a full example how to use it.